# Unresolved reference: field in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to implement the following logic:

```
@Volatile
public var loggedIn = false
    public set(value) {
        if (this.loggedIn != value) {
            this.loggedIn = value
            database.write(LOGGED_IN, value)
        }
    }
```

Of course, this gives me a stack overflow, since in the this.loggedIn = value line the setter is called again and again.

In [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) they say I can set it like this, if the property has a backing field:

```
var counter = 0 // the initializer value is written directly to the backing field
  set(value) {
    if (value >= 0)
      field = value
  }
```

However, I cannot use the field word in my setter, because it says field is an unresolved reference. I don't understand why, this property has a backing field, at least Idea says it.

What now???

Comment: please don't tell me I have to use a backing property.

Comment: Does removing the @Volatile annotation change things? Only thing I can think of that's wrong, unless you're on an old Kotlin version. The field syntax was only added in 13 or 14

Comment: I'm using the latest available Kotlin on Android, 14. Removing the volatile doesn't help. :( I need it to be volatile anyways.

Comment: I just pasted your code into Android Studio and it worked perfectly. What's your exact version code for kotlin-stdlib as well as your AS plugin version?

Comment: I wrote my previous answer from my sleeping bed. I didn't remember well, because I was using M13. I updated to 1.0.0-beta, and now it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aaron Sarazan suggested in the comments of the question: I wasn't using the newest available Kotlin. Upgrading from M13 to 1.0.0-beta solved my problem.